# How can I extract the integers/floats and symbol out of a string like "1823917+3"?

Tags: javascript, regex

I receive strings like "5+3" or "98171982739187.3 / 2.1" and need to extract each integer/float from that particular string and the symbol used in the expression. I don't know exactly how big the numbers will be but the expression is always in the form of *NumberSYMBOLNumber*.

I tried to do Regex101 research. I was able to get the digits but not the numbers.

What have I tried:

```
"5234234+323423.3".match(/\d/g)
```

What I want to achieve:

"5123123"

"+"

"31.91123"

Symbols accepted in the expression: "+ - * / .(decimal point)"
No e notation used.

Comment: Do you care about things like scientific notation (3.4e10)? What symbols do you want to accept? Everything that's not a number, or only a subset?

Comment: Probably, split with `/([-+\/*])/`, `s.split(/([-+\/*])/)`, will do.

Comment: @JoachimSauer No scientific notation used, just numbers from 0-9 and symbols: + - * / and decimal point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the list of symbols or the number you'd like to capture.

`\d+(\.\d+)?` targets natural numbers or decimal values (note that `1.` will be captured as `1`)

**Solution:**

```js
console.log(
  "5234234+323423.3".match(/\+|\-|\*|\/|\d+(\.\d+)?/g)
)
```

**Testing with multiple values:**

```js
const values = [
 "12",
 "12.21*122.2222222",
 "123+321-1.12*7/3.91"
]

const res = values.map(value=>value.match(/\+|\-|\*|\/|\d+(\.\d+)?/g));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider NUMBER as "some digits that may be followed by a dot and more digits"

Consider SYMBOL as "+" or "-" or "/" or "*"

You can use the following regex:

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(\+|\-|\/|\*)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

You got 3 capturing groups there:

1. `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - NUMBER
2. `(\+|\-|\/|\*)` - SYMBOL
3. `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - NUMBER

Note the non capturing groups within 1 and 3, e.g. (?: ...)

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/axSr7m/1